# Crontab cannot execute

Tags: linux, shell, cron

I tried to use crontab to execute my py file everyday, but it can only create empty log file

```
0 8 * * * /usr/local/bin/python3 /Users/UserName/Downloads/Crawling_1.py > /Users/UserName/Downloads/log.log
```

Then I tried to use SHELL file to execute a simple demand, if I put log file settings inside .sh file, no log file was created. Similarly, the crontab did not execute when I put python3 demand inside the SHELL file.

```
echo 1 > /Users/UserName/Downloads/new_log.log > /Users/UserName/Downloads/log.log
```

But if I directly run echo in Crontab, it can work out perfectly.

```
* * * * * echo 1 > /Users/UserName/Downloads/new_log.log
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? Thank you so much.

Comment: `>` overwrites existing data. You should use `>>`. But also you should be sure that your tool executes. Look at error messages of cronttab (either on system log, or as a email). I assume you misses some env variables (e.g. where python modules are)

Answer (score 0):

Try it with `>>`:

```
0 8 * * * /usr/local/bin/python3 /Users/UserName/Downloads/Crawling_1.py >> /Users/UserName/Downloads/log.log
```

then with `>>` it will create a file if it doesn't exist. If the file existe, it will be appended to the end of the file.

With `>` the whole file will replace it, if the **file exist**. If the file *not exist**, nothing happens.

You can do the command also with `>`, but be sure, that the `.log`-file, where you will write inside, exist!

Comment: I have also tried >>, but both symbols cannot work within SHELL script.